# Como usar um if dentro do outro?

Tags: c++, if, else

O problema é o seguinte 2 times de futebol, queria criar um decisão onde mostraria "Brasil ganhou" ou "Argentina Ganhou" ou "Houve empate".

Porém não consigo criar três decisões, segue abaixo meu código.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a, b;

    cout<<"Digite quantos Gol(s) o Brasil fez: ";
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"Digite quantos Gol(s) a Argentina fez: ";
    cin>>a;

    if (b>a){
        cout<<"\nBrasil ganhou com "<<b<<"Gol(s)\n";
        /*if (b==a){
            cout<<"Brasil e Argentina empatou, ambos com "<<a<<"Gol(s)";
        }*/

    }
    else (a==b)
        cout<<"Houve empate. "<<a<<"Gol(s)";

    else 
        cout<<"\nArgetina ganhou com "<<a<<"Gol(s)\n";

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Se ainda não o fez, veja o [tour] como proceder. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

Você não quer fazer um dentro do outro, embora isso até funcionaria, mas não é o ideal, o melhor é fazê-los em sequência:

```
int main() {
    int a, b;
    cout << "Digite quantos Gol(s) o Brasil fez: ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Digite quantos Gol(s) a Argentina fez: ";
    cin >> a;
    if (b > a) cout << "\nBrasil ganhou com "<< b << "Gol(s)\n";
    else if (a == b) cout << "Houve empate. " << a << "Gol(s)";
    else cout << "\nArgetina ganhou com " << a << "Gol(s)\n";
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/8Wzx1B). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/eurlnwgw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/SimpleComparison.cpp).

Comment: No final um  else if não seria um if aninhado no else?

Comment: @Guto, na verdade sim, o `if` reside dentro do `else`, mas se costuma não usar as chaves no `else`, nesse caso, por questão de semântica, dando a impressão do `else if` ser uma estrutura única.
Um jeito interessante de se usar o `else if` é com macros `#define elif else if` assim cria uma estrutura unica. `if(true){...}elif(!false){...}elif(a==b){...}`

Answer (score 1):

Você deve usar o `else if(statement)`que significa: "SE NÃO PASSAR NO IF DE CIMA, TENTE ESTE".

No seu caso vai ficar:

```
cout<<"Digite quantos Gol(s) o Brasil fez: ";
cin>>b;
cout<<"Digite quantos Gol(s) a Argentina fez: ";
cin>>a;

if (b>a){
    cout<<"\nBrasil ganhou com "<<b<<"Gol(s)\n";
    /*if (b==a){
        cout<<"Brasil e Argentina empatou, ambos com "<<a<<"Gol(s)";
    }*/

}
else if(a==b){
    cout<<"Houve empate. "<<a<<"Gol(s)";

} else {
    cout<<"\nArgetina ganhou com "<<a<<"Gol(s)\n";
}

return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cout<<"Digite quantos Gol(s) o Brasil fez: ";
cin>>b;
cout<<"Digite quantos Gol(s) a Argentina fez: ";
cin>>a;

if (b>a){
    cout<<"\nBrasil ganhou com "<<b<<"Gol(s)\n";
}else{ 
    if (b==a){
        cout<<"Brasil e Argentina empatou, ambos com "<<a<<"Gol(s)";
    }else{
       cout<<"\nArgetina ganhou com "<<a<<"Gol(s)\n";
   }
}

return 0;
```